# CasperJs : How can I submit a Form that has action="" (That has no action)

Tags: forms, casperjs

In the sample code in the documentation of casperjs, submitting form is through this:

```
var loginFormSelector = 'form[name="loginForm"]';
casper.waitForSelector(loginFormSelector,
        function() {
            this.echo("Login page loaded. Entering in username and password");
            this.fillSelectors(loginFormSelector, {
                'input#username': username,
                'input#password': password'
            }, true);
        },
        function() {
            this.die("Login form not found");
        });
```

My Error Log

```
Login page loaded. Entering in username and password
[info] [remote] attempting to fetch form element from selector: 'form[name="loginForm"]'
[debug] [remote] Set "username" field value to usrname
[debug] [remote] Set "password" field value to ***********
[info] [remote] submitting form to unknown, HTTP POST
[info] [phantom] Step anonymous 4/5: done in 14362ms.
```

Comment: And where exactly would you like to submit this form?